# How to handle error in Angular by using snackbar

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, angular-material, ngrx

My task is to add error handling in this code but not really sure how to do this so I would be really appreciated If I can get any suggestion or help.

Just want to add A snack bar saying "Error has occurred" if it didn't save because of network issue or something.

```
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';

saveClick(){
  this.store.dispatch(updateChart({chart: this.chart}))
}
```

Comment: Which store management are you using ? NGRX ? tell us please, the answer can be different depending on this.

Comment: hi Quentin. Yes it's ngrx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it is the good way of doing it, but you could call your snackbar in your effect.

When getting the returned value of your api call, either return a success action or an error action (or call your snackbar directly).

Based on the documentation, here is what your effect would look like:

```
export class MovieEffects {
 
  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
    mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => {
          /* Call snackbar here, or return an error action */
          this._snackBar.open('Snackbar message');
        })
      ))
    )
  );
 
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private moviesService: MoviesService,
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) {}
}
```

Note the use `catchError` from rxjs which is triggered if you api call return something different than a valid HttpResponse (With 2xx code I guess).

Comment: by anychance can you show me how cuz I'm not really getting it. Thank you

Comment: @aaselab I have edited my answer. You can also check others answers since tey seems accurate as well

Comment: HI Quentin, by any chance can you show me how to call snackbar on cathError()? thank you

Comment: I edited my answer to call a simple snackbar. Note the private injection in the constructor. You'll alswo have to import MatSnackBarModule in your app.module and MatSnackBar in your MovieEffects files. Refer to https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview to learn more about snackbar, it's pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to Error actions in your component and then display you errors as a side effects, don't do it in the Effect file in order to keep it clean.
let's say you have an UPDATE_ERROR action.

you will of course return a new action "update_failed" in case of an error updating you data, you will have somthing like this in your effect file:

```
...
catchError(error => of(new yourActions.UpdateError({ error })))
```

and then you can listen to your "UPDATE_ERROR" action, whenever it's dispatched you can show your snackbar to show error, because you are subscribing to it in your component like the following :

```
 constructor(public store: Store<fromRoot.State>, private actions$: Actions) {
  this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(yourActions.ChartActionTypes.Failure),
   tap(_ => {
    this.snackBar.open("Update failed", action, { duration: 2000,});
   }));
}
```

Comment: Hi Fateh, thanks for this but I'm so confused. I thought it will be much simpler but can you please explain me more about what is going in your code  and what happend to my UpdateChart?. thankx

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ngrx to store data, you must create three actions for each asynchronous event, for example, to get a profile: GetProfile, GetProfileSuccess, GetProfileFailed. Further for working with the API we usually use effects, in total we have a reducer, actions and effects for working with a profile (for example). And when we do an asynchronous event, we throw an error action or provide success action. Effects file:

```
  public loadProfile$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ProfileApiActionTypes.GetProfile),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.profileDataService.getProfile().pipe(
          map(({data}) => getProfileSuccessAction({ data })),
          catchError((error) => of(getProfileFaildAction({ payload: error }))),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

In the same file we handle error action in effect:

```
  public profileError$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(
        ProfileApiActionTypes.GetProfileFailed,
      ),
      tap(({ payload }) => {
        // your logic with snackbar
      },
    ),
    { dispatch: false },
  );
```